Раздать данные многим с одного вебсокета
Есть АПИ сервер с данными, которые приходят по вебсокету. Туда я могу подключить только одного клиента - себя.
Мне нужно эти данные раздавать другим уже из моего вебсокета.
То есть
я подключаюсь и получаю постоянно данные, без остановки. Это как цены с бирж когда идут потоком.
А вот потом мне нужно создать свой сервер и эти данные раздавать тем, кто уже подключается ко мне. То есть я как посредник, раздаю данные из одного канала. Смысл в том, что нужна минимальная зарежка которая только может быть.
Вопрос в том, какой вебсокет поддерживает это на PHP, чтобы не использовать сторонние библиотеки или что-то типа редиса.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Используйте Ratchet, но библиотеки по-любому придется использовать так как websocketа нативно нет в PHP, есть только обычные сокеты.

@DanielProtopopov а как же файберы?

@АлексейШиманский а при чём здесь fibers? Fibers - это облегченная версия потока
